# How to show only volume control in AVPlayerviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm making demo to play a simple video from url.
I can play the video successfully and can disable all controls
How can i show only volume control?

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class TestViewController: UIViewController {

       let videoURL = URL(string: "https://demo-available.com/send2hub/assets/uploads/video/1570194354.mp4")
       
       var player : AVPlayer?
       var playerLayer : AVPlayerLayer?
       let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
 //hide all controls of  player controller
       playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = false

       override func viewDidLoad() {
       player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
       playerViewController.player = player
       self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {   
         self.playerViewController.player!.play()
      }
}
```

Comment: AVPlayer class has [volume](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1390127-volume) property. Add your custom slider and update the volume when its value changes.

Comment: Yes. I did it. Thank you

Comment: Happy to help :)